# I am a beginner in angularjs, what is wrong in following code there is no error but the result is not show in view

Tags: angularjs

### //anular model

```
       var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
```

### // this is a service to get data

```
        app.service('EmployeeService', function ($http) {
            this.getEmployees = function () {
                return this.$http.get('Employee/getall');
            }
        });
```

### // angular controller

```
        app.controller('EmployeeController', function ($scope, EmployeeService) {
            function getEmployeeList() {
                EmployeeService.getEmployeeList.then(function (emp) {
                    $scope.EmployeeList = emp.data;
                }, function (error) {
                });
            }
        });
```

## // controller return json result

```
public JsonResult getall()
{
       List<Countries> contry = new List<Countries>() { 
       new Countries({id=1,Name="ahmad" ,LastName="ali" },
       new Countries() {id=1,Name="kami" ,LastName="ali" },
       new Countries() {id=1,Name="billo" ,LastName="ali" },
       new Countries() {id=1,Name="juni" ,LastName="ali" },
       new Countries() {id=1,Name="podeena" ,LastName="ali" }                            };
      return Json(contry, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }
```

### this is view

id
                Name
                Last Name
            
            
                {{e.id}}
                {{e.Name}}
                {{e.LastName}}

### these are links

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Angular/Module.js"></script>
<script src="~/Angular/Service.js"></script>
<script src="~/Angular/empController.js"></script>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Minor issue. You want an employee list, but are returning a list of countries object. on the line `$scope.EmployeeList = emp.data` be `$scope.EmployeeList = emp.country`. Where the code to display EmployeeList? Have you placed a breakpoint at the point $scope.EmployeeList get's set to ensure the data is getting back.

Comment: i changed but the data is not displaying $scope.EmployeeList = emp.data be $scope.EmployeeList = emp.country

Comment: Can you place a breakpoint through Chrome or something at the point where the list should be getting set and check that emp has an object attached and is populated

Comment: if emp looks to be populated with the correct data/object name, then on the next line try `$scope().$digest()`

Comment: place a breakpoint in the GetAll method, does the method get called. You have a missing closing bracket in this method

Comment: did you read my last comment. Your GetAll method has a missing closing bracket. Does the $http.Get call to the method get into the method.?